# Capture changes to fillable PDF displayed in browser

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-mvc-4, user-input

A requirement for the site I am developing is for users to be able to view, fill out and submit PDFs that have been uploaded to the site by admins. Currently, in order for a user to do this they need to download the PDF, open it, fill it out, save it, and then upload it. This works but is obviously a bit clunky.

```
<object id="AttPdf" type="application/pdf" 
        data="@Url.Action("Attachment", new { id = Model.AttachmentId })"/>
```

I'd like to be able to simplify the process by enabling the user to edit the PDF inside the browser and hit a submit button to send it back without having to download/modify/save/upload. Possible?

Comment: Why not use a real form, instead of a PDF?

Comment: cpf: the PDFs are dynamic - uploaded by 'admins' of the site for user review. I've updated the question to hopefully be a little more clear.

Comment: Have you considered something like Adobe LiveCycle? That's the only thing I can think that would allow the contents of fillable PDF forms to automatically be sent back to the server without the save->upload step. Of course, it only works when using Acrobat Reader, and no doubt costs a fortune.